# How to periodically send GPS location to a mysql server over HTTP?

Tags: gps, geolocation

I am looking for a way to send every x seconds my gps location to my mysql db.

What I need is the lat/long, speed and direction. I want that my phone send it to a website. So every x seconds it will need to do something like this:

```
HTTP GET http://www.mydomain.com/gps.php?lat=000&long=000&speed=000&dir=000
```

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) // A hint, though: You might want to take a look at *Tasker*, which can do things like HTTP POST (where you can freely adjust the URL to your needs).

Comment: Post this question on http://www.stackoverflow.com/